# Entity Framework migration automatically sets defaults

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with the Npgsql provider on a PostgreSQL database. I have a code-first migration created from this class:

```
public class CarriedItem : IItem {
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarriedItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool GameOrPay { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I generated the migration file and created the table, but I noticed all of the `Required` attributes were given default values in the database, which would make it harder to enforce the `NOT NULL` restriction from the database. So in the migration I set `defaultValueSql` properties on the columns.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.CarriedItems",
    c => new {
        CarriedItemId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        Size = c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "1"),
        Name = c.String(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: null),
        Description = c.String(),
        GameOrPay = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: null),
        Cost = c.String(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: null),
    })
    .Index(c => c.Name, unique: true)
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.CarriedItemId);
```

I dropped and re-created the database and ran the migration again. It didn't seem to make any difference. I can look at the table it generated in PGAdmin and see the default values are still set on `NOT NULL` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo."CarriedItems"
(
  "CarriedItemId" serial NOT NULL,
  "Size" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  "Name" text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  "Description" text,
  "GameOrPay" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  "Cost" text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_dbo.CarriedItems" PRIMARY KEY ("CarriedItemId")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Is there a setting I can use to prevent the default values? What I would like the table to look like is this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo."CarriedItems"
(
  "CarriedItemId" serial NOT NULL,
  "Size" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  "Name" text NOT NULL,
  "Description" text,
  "GameOrPay" boolean NOT NULL,
  "Cost" text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_dbo.CarriedItems" PRIMARY KEY ("CarriedItemId")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: your question is not clear for me.Do you need to set default values by yourself or what ? If a field is `required` then you cannot set a `NULL` value for that field.

Comment: I think you are using TPH (CarriedItem : IItem) the problem TPH, multiple classes share the same table. Think about this use case: "A" is a class has required property TestProp, how can the database restrict this column as read only and what happened if another inhertied class try to add a new  row?  If you need more information just check this this section on "TPH Requires Properties in SubClasses to be Nullable in the Database"   http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: @Sampath I would like the database to throw an error if the field is null, so that any application accessing the database will not be able to save a record if required fields are null. There may be a scenario when some other another application does not set the `Required` attribute on the property in the model. If they leave the `GameOrPay` field blank, the application will not throw and error and the database will default to false. This could cause problems.

Comment: @BassamAlugili `IItem` is an interface, so it should not be using TPH. I'm not sure if there is something behind the scenes that implementing TPH requirements because it sees this connection. But I have other models, such as a `Job` model, that does not use any interface and still has the `[Required]` properties automatically given a `DEFAULT` in the database.

Comment: Sorry but I think @Sampath has right it is not clear what you want to do? if you put required on the field => Not Null is correct. If you do not need the default value you can just remove it.  If you want Required and allow empty string then you can use this data annoation  ======> [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]

Comment: @BassamAlugili I added an example of what I would like the table to look like. Your comment "If you do not need the default value you can just remove it," sounds like exactly what I am trying to do. The problem is the migration adds `DEFAULT ...` to the database column whether I include `defaultValueSql: null` or not. I do not want to allow empty strings.

Comment: what did you mean by this `I do not want to allow empty strings` ? if you remove `required` fields on `string` then it'll allow `null` on the db no ? is that an issue for you ?

Comment: @Sampath I would like the validation check by both the application and the database. Using the `[Required]` attribute allows me to validate in the application. Using `NOT NULL` in the database allows me to validate in the database. If the database also has a default value, for example `NOT NULL DEFAULT false`, then the validation provided by `NOT NULL` will never be triggered, and the database would use the default value rather than reject the record.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the migration source code, method AppendColumn, your case is probably this

```
else if (column.IsNullable != null 
    && !column.IsNullable.Value 
    && (column.StoreType == null || 
    (column.StoreType.IndexOf("rowversion", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1))) 
{ 
    sql.Append(" DEFAULT "); 
    AppendValue(column.ClrDefaultValue, sql); 
}
```

so if you specify storeType it should work.

Comment: If I edit the name column to `Name = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "character varying")`, it still adds the default only now its: `"Name" character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying`.

Comment: It could be that you have a different version of the provider. Still looking at the source code ( https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator.cs ) you could try to set default value to null.